# Access function argument in different function?

Tags: php, function, attributes, arguments

I have this function:

```
<?php myWidget() { ?>

         <div id="<?php echo $args['widget_id']; ?>">
              <p>Something</p>
         </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

(widget_id is Wordpress core function so I have no direct access to that, it just simply generates widgets name)

I wanted to add my widget as a shortcode so needed to create another function:

```
function myWidget_shortcode( $atts ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        /* attributes here */
        ), $atts ) );

        ob_start();    
        the_widget(myWidget);
        return ob_get_clean();
}
```

the_widget just simply calls widget called myWidget.

The point is, everything works good, but id=" " is always empty when I use the second code.

I know it's a Wordpress question, but I believe this has more to do with my PHP code.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's certainly also a PHP issue, but you might get more concrete help on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ (flag for moderator attention, and have your question moved)

Comment: The first snippet is no valid PHP code.

Comment: Is the first example some kind of Wordpress template maybe?

Comment: @rik, @David Mårtensson, my mistake, it was just an example :)

Comment: Can you test if $args is set before calling myWidget? Maybe the code normaly calling  myWidget sets the $args array while your code does not?

Comment: @David Mårtensson, Adding echo $args['widget_id']; after ob_start(); shows also nothing if that's what you meant :(

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your last comment the problem is that $args is not set and since the ID is set from $args it will "".

You have to find out where $args is set and either make sure that part is run or set it your self.

$args in this case is not arguments to myWidget method but a global array.

Check if it exists at all

```
isset($args)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is its a scope issue. `$args` isnt inside the function. Try passing it to the function